# Display div if a specific select option value is selected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display a div if user select a specific option value from a select drop down list.

Example:

The select drop down list consist of dynamic names fetched from the database and also one static or permanent name at the bottom of the list called "Admin"

If user select an option that's not "Admin", a div containing certain form element is shown else if the user select "Admin" that div remain hidden

Here is my code:

Javascript -

```
<script language="javascript">

function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
{
    if(nameSelect){
        admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
        if(admOptionValue != 0){
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }
}

</script>
```

HTML -

```
<select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this.select);">
<option value="1">Jay</option>
<option value="4">Sam</option>
<option id="admOption" value="0">Admin</option>
</select>


<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
admin selected
</div>
```

Would be glad getting help with this.

Comment: To everyone who posted an answer and also made comment regarding my question, I'm saying Thank You! I'm very grateful to u guys. @Darren Davies, I really appreciate your answer being the first to make an attempt to help out. Thanks. To others, thanks a million!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `this.select` is incorrect.

Here is the correct code:

**HTML**

```
<select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
<option value="1">Jay</option>
<option value="4">Sam</option>
<option id="admOption" value="0">Admin</option>
</select>


<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
admin selected
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
{
    console.log(nameSelect);
    if(nameSelect){
        admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
        if(admOptionValue == nameSelect.value){
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

See the demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaVBZ/1/).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need like this

Just Change this line:

**JS**

```
admOptionValue = document.getElementById("getFname").value;
//alert(admOptionValue);

if(admOptionValue == 0){
     document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "";
}
else{
     document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
 }
```

And also in **HTML**

`onchange="admSelectCheck(this);"`

[**see Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/FhZu7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

JS:

```
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
{
    if(nameSelect){
        admOptionValue = nameSelect.value;
        if(admOptionValue != 0){
            nameSelect.style.display = "";
        }
        else{
            nameSelect.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        nameSelect.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
<option value="1">Jay</option>
<option value="4">Sam</option>
<option id="admOption" value="0">Admin</option>
</select>

<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
admin selected
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach change event handler on body **load** event and hide/unhide `<div>` based on selection:

HTML

```
<select id="getFname">
  <option value="1">Jay</option>
  <option value="4">Sam</option>
  <option id="admOption" value="0">Admin</option>
</select>


<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
   admin selected
</div>
```

Put the following code in Head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onload() {
   document.getElementById("getFname").onchange = function (e) {
   if (this.value == 0) {
     document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display="";
   } else {
     document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display="none";
  }
 };

}

</script>
```

Call the onload function in body:

```
<body onload="onload()">
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FuYaj/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
    <option value="1">Jay</option>
    <option value="4">Sam</option>
    <option id="admOption" value="0">Admin</option>
</select>


<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
    admin selected
</div>
```

And

```
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
{
    var val = nameSelect.options[nameSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = val == '0' ? "block" : 'none';
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kuZMu/)

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.select` to `this`:

```
 <select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
```

Then it should work okay. Also if you have `jQuery` you can simply do:

```
$("#getFname").change(function() {
   var val = $(this).text();
   if (val != "Admin") {
      $("#div").show();
   }
});
```

Will supply a pure JS function too.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast - I said I will post a pure JS solution also.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although I would prefer to have this done via javascript without jquery but all the same i will try this out to see the result. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="getFname">
<option value="1">Jay</option>
<option value="4">Sam</option>
<option value="0">Admin</option>
</select>


<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
admin selected
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#getFname").on("change",function(){"0"===$(this).val()?$("#admDivCheck").show():$("#admDivCheck").hide()});
</script>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/kingtaherkings/swzmxkej/