# Show input field only if a specific option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-select

I'm trying to make a form which checks if a certain option is selected from a "select" tag. Here is my current HTML:

```
<select onchange="yesnoCheck()">
    <option id="noCheck" value="">Valitse automerkkisi</option>
    <option id="noCheck" value="lada">Lada</option>
    <option id="noCheck" value="mosse">Mosse</option>
    <option id="noCheck" value="volga">Volga</option>
    <option id="noCheck" value="vartburg">Vartburg</option>
    <option id="yesCheck" value="other">Muu</option>
</select>
```

This is the div element which should become visible after "Muu" is selected:

```
<div id="ifYes" style="display: none;">
    <label for="car">Muu, mikä?</label> <input type="text" id="car" name="car" /><br />
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript I'm trying to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function yesnoCheck() {
        if (document.getElementById("yesCheck").checked) {
            document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

But it's not working...

Comment: Solved it! In the if-function I have ".checked" there but it should be ".selected"

Answer (score 55, accepted):

here you go:

```js
function yesnoCheck(that) {
    if (that.value == "other") {
  alert("check");
        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
    <option value="">Valitse automerkkisi</option>
    <option value="lada">Lada</option>
    <option value="mosse">Mosse</option>
    <option value="volga">Volga</option>
    <option value="vartburg">Vartburg</option>
    <option value="other">Muu</option>
</select>

<div id="ifYes" style="display: none;">
    <label for="car">Muu, mikä?</label> <input type="text" id="car" name="car" /><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out: [Display div if a specific select option value is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712941/display-div-if-a-specific-select-option-value-is-selected)

Also don't use ID use data attributes or value to check comparison.

Comment: ID's should be unique and getElementByID only returns one

Comment: You could also use classes for this but I think data-attributes or using value is better. With jQuery your code would look like in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/s33q3j5u/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function yesnoCheck(that) {
        if (that.value == "other") {
            document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
        }elseif (that.value == "lada") {
            
} else {
            document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    <select onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
        <option value="">Valitse automerkkisi</option>
        <option value="lada">Lada</option>
        <option value="mosse">Mosse</option>
        <option value="volga">Volga</option>
        <option value="vartburg">Vartburg</option>
        <option value="other">Muu</option>
    </select>

    <div id="ifYes" style="display: none;">
        <label for="car">Muu, mikä?</label> <input type="text" id="car" name="car" /><br />
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing with an answer but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function yesnoCheck(that) 
{
    if (that.value == "aadhar") 
    {
        document.getElementById("adc").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("adc").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (that.value == "pan")
    {
        document.getElementById("pc").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("pc").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (that.value == "pass")
    {
        document.getElementById("ps").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("ps").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div>

    <select id="selector" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
        <option value="select">__Select__</option>
        <option value="aadhar">Aadhaar Card</option>
        <option value="pan">Pan Card</option>
        <option value="pass">Passport</option>
    </select>
    <label for="selector">Select ID Proof</label>
</div>

<div id="adc" style="display: none;">
    <label for="aadhar">Enter Aadhar Card No.</label> 
    <input type="text" id="aadhar" name="aadhar" /><br />
</div>
<div id="pc" style="display: none;">
    <label for="pan">Enter Pan Card No.</label> 
    <input type="text" id="pan" name="pan" /><br />
</div>
<div id="ps" style="display: none;">
    <label for="pass">Enter Passport No.</label> 
    <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.