# Need a form field to be shown depending on the results of another field

Tags: javascript, html, css

Looking for some help here.

I have a HTML page with a form that includes multiple input fields.

One of those fields is dropdown-box with multiple values , being one of the the option "Other".

What i need to do here is to have an input text box show up if the user selects the Other option.

So to sum it up , i need a function that will show the hidden form field if that value is selected.
This needs to be done before submission , so using onexit() or anything like this.

I have been searching but i am not able to find a way to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/icomoon/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <!-- Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <title>Pedido de Assistência Técnica</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["brat"]["Marca"].value;
        var y = document.forms["brat"]["outram"].value;
        if (x == "" && y=="") {
          alert("Necessita de seleccionar uma marca");
          return false;
        }
      }
      </script>


  <div class="d-lg-flex half">
    <div class="bg order-1 order-md-2" style="background-image: url('images/bgbr.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="contents order-2 order-md-1">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-7 py-5">
            <h3>Pedido de Assistência</h3>
            <p class="mb-4">Por favor preencha o formulário com os dados correctos.</p>
            <form action="#" method="post" name="brat" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group first">
                    <label for="fname">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" id="fname">
                  </div>    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group first">
                    <label for="fmorada">Morada</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Morada" id="fmorada">
                  </div>    
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group first">
                    <label for="lemail">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="xxxx@xxxxx.xx" id="lemail">
                  </div>    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group first">
                    <label for="ltelefone">Telefone</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="9xxxxxxxx" id="ltelefone">
                  </div>    
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
              
                  <div class="form-group first">
                    <label for="codpostal">Cod.Postal</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="XXXX-XXX" id="codpostal">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
              
                  <div class="form-group first">
                    <label for="localidade">Localidade</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Localidade" id="localidade">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
              
                  <div class="form-group first">
                    <label for="NIF">NIF</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nif" id="NIF">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
              
                  <div class="form-group first">
                    <label for="obs">Observações</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Observações" id="obs">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
              
                  <div class="form-group first">
                    <label for="marca">Marca</label>
                    <select name="Marca" class="form-control" id="Marca">
                      <option value="" selected>Selecione uma marca</option>
                      <option value="ALBATROSS">ALBATROSS</option>
                      <option value="BERING">BERING</option>
                      <option value="BOSS">BOSS</option>
                      <option value="CERTINA">CERTINA</option>
                      <option value="CK">CK</option>
                      <option value="ELETTA">ELETTA</option>
                      <option value="GUCCI">GUCCI</option>
                      <option value="HAMILTON">HAMILTON</option>
                      <option value="LACOSTE">LACOSTE</option>
                      <option value="LONGINES">LONGINES</option>
                      <option value="OMEGA">OMEGA</option>
                      <option value="PIERRE BALMAIN">PIERRE BALMAIN</option>
                      <option value="RADO">RADO</option>
                      <option value="SCUDERIA FERRARI">SCUDERIA FERRARI</option>
                      <option value="TECHNOMARINE">TECHNOMARINE</option>
                      <option value="TECHNOSPORT">TECHNOSPORT</option>
                      <option value="TISSOT">TISSOT</option>
                      <option value="TOMMY HILFIGER">TOMMY HILFIGER</option>
                      <option value="ZENO">ZENO</option>
                      <option value="OUTRAS">Outras</option>
                  </select> 
          
                  </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group last mb-3">
                    <label for="outram">Outras Marcas</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Outra Marca" id="outram" name="outram">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="d-flex mb-5 mt-4 align-items-center">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <label class="control control--checkbox mb-0"><span class="caption">Ao solicitar a assistência está a concordar com os&nbsp; <a href="https://boutiquedosrelogios.pt/termos-condicoes" target="_new">Termos e Condições.</a></span>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="termos" required/>
                  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                </label>
              </div>
              </div>

              <input type="submit" value="Solicitar Assistência" class="btn px-5 btn-primary">

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    
  </div>
    
    

    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add some of your code showing how you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: Hi Priyesha,

Thank you for your answer. That is the thing , i don't have code for that since i am not able to do it or to find how.
The page has a simple form validation JS in place but it is not what i need , i will try to post the code that i have so far.

Comment: Check out this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321494/show-input-field-only-if-a-specific-option-is-selected
I think it answers your query

Comment: Great link , Issue resolved , thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS-property `display` of the -element depending on chosen value in the drop down.

```js
document.querySelector("#dropdown").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const other = document.querySelector("#other");
  if (e.target.value === "other") {
    other.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    other.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#other {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<br>
<input id="other" type="text">
```