# Hide/show fields based on a choice

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am new to js (job description didn't mention it, but can't complain as I am second year cs student), and I am trying to show appropriate fields based on the option which user chooses.

[That's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp3DU.png)

There are two options - "linear" and "non-linear". The second one should display cutoff, before cutoff, after cutoff, ID, and ADD NON-LINEAR ROW button. The first one should not display anything except the first row.

Select part:

```
<div class="col-xl-3">
    {{render_field(calculation_form.calculation_method,class="form-select mb-3") }}
</div>
```

Whole html part:

```
<div class="card-text">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-3">
                            {{render_field(calculation_form.calculation_name,class="form-control mb-3") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-3">
                            {{render_field(calculation_form.calculation_date,class="form-control mb-3",
                            value=current_project['project_date']|format_datetime)}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-3">
                            {{render_field(calculation_form.calculation_method,class="form-select mb-3") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-3">
                          {{render_field(calculation_form.calculation_type,class="form-select mb-3") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-xl-3'>
                          <form id="cutoff_form">
                            <label for="cutoff">Cutoff</label><br>
                            <input id ='cutoff', class="form-control mb-3", placeholder="0.983">
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-xl-3'>
                          <form id="before_cutoff_form">
                            <label for="before_cutoff">Before cutoff</label><br>
                            <input id ='before_cutoff', class="form-control mb-3", placeholder="0.6">
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-xl-3'>
                          <form id="after_cutoff_form">
                            <label for="after_cutoff">After cutoff</label><br>
                            <input id ='after_cutoff', class="form-control mb-3", placeholder="0.4">
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-xl-3'>
                          <form id="row_id_form">
                            <label for="row_id">Row ID</label><br>
                            <input id ='row_id', class="form-control mb-3", placeholder="115">
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end">
                          <input id='calculation_add_extra_args', class="btn btn-primary compass-btn", type="button", value="ADD NON-LINEAR ROW">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Any tip or link to similiar thread would be appreciated, as I couldn't find anything myself.

Comment: I mean you can use JS or Jquery to hide or show fields by the options, this post should help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321494/show-input-field-only-if-a-specific-option-is-selected

Comment: @JanKees Thanks!  About to check this